# Perfomance in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, servlets

I've got an app that adds file's content row by row into data base. If file is not so big (smaller, than 100 kB) it will work well, but I can not say the same about big files. I found out that `INSERT` query takes about 1 msc, so 50k `INSERT` takes 50 sec. I find it very slow. This is my plan:

- if file is big enough, do `INSERT` in another thread
- if not, do it synchronously

So, every user will run new thread, if file is big. I mean that I can not use one instance of this thread, every user will run new. Is it a good idea or not? How would you do?

Comment: Spring has support for async tasks. See `@Async` annotation or chapter "Task Execution and Scheduling" in reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

- Why don't you use batch updates? I mean doing several inserts to database at one time. Network round trip costs a lot of time, you can increase the performance significantly.
- Performing update asynchronously is a good idea. But actually it **doesn't mean** that you need to create new **thread per user**. It can be a fixed pool of threads (let's say 5) to do the job for all the users.